# Counting the sum of a series based on the Index name in python

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, sum, series

I have the following series:

```
Index   Count
A        2
B        5
C        3
D        1
E        6
```

I want to count A as NO1, B and D as NO2, C and E as NO3. (NOTE that NO1, NO2 and NO3 are categories and there is no pattern to follow).

Therefore the results will be

```
NO1 = 2
No2 = 6
No3 = 9
```

I tried to use `pd.Series([]).sum()` and the result is `0`, but it gave me this warning:

```
DeprecationWarning: The default dtype for empty Series will be 'object' instead of 'float64' in a future version. Specify a dtype explicitly to silence this warning.
```

Anyone who could shed light on this? I'm actually new to python.

Comment: `pd.Series([]).sum()` means "create a new Series with nothing in it, and get the sum of that Series". It has nothing to do with the Series you already have. Anyway, it's not at all clear how you want this to work. What is the rule that tells you that value A should be part of the no1 sum, and not part of either of the other sums? How about all of the others? I can't tell what the pattern is supposed to be.

Comment: Actually there is no pattern. NO1 NO2 and NO3 are categories. If the index name falls on that category, then it should be counted.

Comment: What does "if the index name falls on that category" mean? I don't see any relationship between the category name `NO1` and the letter `A`. Is there supposed to be some other data somewhere that tells you which values to add up?

Comment: I already pre-processed the data Karl. So I was just looking on a way to count them instead of using the above mentioned method. BTW, df.groupby worked :)

Comment: The point is, I didn't know what "pre-processing" entailed for your data. Knowing that you can add the category data to the DataFrame, the rest is natural, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best approach would be creating another column for your data identifying if the row is No1, no2 or n3, like this:

```
   count   No
A      2  No1
B      5  No2
C      3  No3
D      1  No2
E      6  No3
```

in this case you can sum using `groupby` like this:

```
df.groupby('No').sum()
```

which gives:

```
      count
No         
No1       2
No2       6
No3       9
```

If you don't want to have fixed `No` and suppose you want to sum A,C and E, you can do like this:

```
df.loc[['A','C','E']].sum()
```

which wil output this:

```
count    11
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is also another alternative :)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do this would be to first convert your series to a DataFrame and then add a new column for the category. You have not provided the mapping for the category, but I'm sure you can figure out how to make a column out of it, looking something like this:

```py
Index   Count  Category
A        2      No1
B        5      No2
C        3      No3
D        1      No2
E        6      No3
```

From here you can very simply find the sum per category using the `DataFrame.groupby` method:

```py
count = df.groupby('Category').Count.sum()
```

```py
      Count
No1      2  
No2      6 
No3      9
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.Series([2,5,3,1,6], index = ['A','B','C','D','E'])
print(df, '\n ---------- \n')

df['NO1'] = df.A
df['No2'] = df.B + df.D
df['No3'] = df.C + df.E
print(df)
```

Output:

```
A    2
B    5
C    3
D    1
E    6
dtype: int64
 ----------

A      2
B      5
C      3
D      1
E      6
NO1    2
No2    6
No3    9
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is also an alternative :)